# How to parse .amf files? PHP

Tags: php, amf, amfphp

I tried amfphp but failed and can not figure out what happend, PHP dies when i try to deserialize it and does not show any fatal error anywhere.

```
$amf = file_get_contents("file.amf");
$amf2 = new AMFObject($amf);
$deserializer2 = new AMFDeserializer($amf2->rawData); 
$deserializer2->deserialize($amf2); <--- dies here
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: please provide a sample AMF file that causes your code to die.

Comment: Here is the file
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zHcG6KuM9SaklHUldMRVVuVlU/view?usp=sharing)